# Express app with EJS template giving Error: Failed to lookup view "/id" in views directory "/home/USER/Desktop/scholarship-app/views"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to render the request url for id in my express app and getting the following error

`Error: Failed to lookup view "/id" in views directory "/home/USER/Desktop/scholarship-app/views"`

here my part of my express app code

```
app.get('/phd/:id', function(req, res) {

    var pdhID = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
    var query = req.query;

    console.log('console: ' + pdhID + 'query: ' + query);

    db.scholarship.findAll({

        where: pdhID
    }).then(function(scholarship) {

        if (scholarship != null) {

            if (query.hasOwnProperty('format') && query.format === 'json') {

                return res.json(scholarship);
            } else {

                var data_scholarship = JSON.stringify(scholarship);
                console.log("rendering the scholarship page" +  data_scholarship );
                //error
                return res.render('/id', {

                    title: data_scholarship.title,
                    css_path: '/public/css/styles.css',
                    keywords: 'phd position, shoclarships for sciences',
                    menu_bar_arr: menu_bar_arr,
                    menu_bar_link: menu_bar_link,
                    current_page: 'about-us',
                    menu_bar_lindx: menu_bar_arr.length - 1,
                    data_scholarship: data_scholarship,
                    error: 0
                });
            }
        } else {

            return res.render('id', {
                error: '404'
            });
        }
    }, function(err) {

        return res.render('id', {
            msg: 'could cnt open the file',
            error: 1
        });
    });
});
```

My id.ejs file is located @ path `/home/USER/Desktop/scholarship-app/views`, still it giving me the error.

It will be great if some one can help it the error. My other view in the same directory is getting render properly

Comment: @ricky  :  cool it worked .. I did not noticed that i have added additional '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove extra `/` from your `id` in `return res.render('/id',{....})`